# How to pass column variables to apply function?

Tags: r

I have this `data.frame`:

```
  id  |  amount1  | amount2  |  day1  |  day2
 ---------------------------------------------
  A   |    10     |    32    |   0    |   34
  B   |    54     |    44    |   8    |   43
  C   |    45     |    66    |   16   |   99    

df <- data.frame(id=c('A','B','C'), amount1=c(10,54,45), amount2=c(32,44,66),  day1=c(0,8,16), day2=c(34,43,99))
```

on which I would like to `apply` a function

```
df$res <-  apply(df, 1, myfunc)
```

where

```
myfunc <- function(x,y) sum(x) * mean(y)
```

only I'd like to pass the column variables as argument to the function, so that it basically should read

```
 apply(df, 1, myfunc, c(amount1, amount2), c(day1, day2))
```

for the first row this is

```
myfunc(c(10,32),c(0,34))
# [1] 714
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
df$res <- apply(df, 1, function(x) myfunc(as.numeric(x[c("amount1", "amount2")]),
                                          as.numeric(x[c("day1", "day2")])))
```

but consider `plyr::adply` as an alternative:

```
library(plyr)
adply(df, 1, transform, res = myfunc(c(amount1, amount2), c(day1, day2)))
#   id amount1 amount2 day1 day2    res
# 1  A      10      32    0   34  714.0
# 2  B      54      44    8   43 2499.0
# 3  C      45      66   16   99 6382.5
```

Answer (score 4):

The `data.table` solution.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df) # don't depend on `id` column as it may not be unique
# instead use 1:nrow(dt) in `by` argument
dt[, res := myfunc(c(amount1,amount2), c(day1, day2)), by=1:nrow(dt)]
> dt
#    id amount1 amount2 day1 day2    res
# 1:  A      10      32    0   34  714.0
# 2:  B      54      44    8   43 2499.0
# 3:  C      45      66   16   99 6382.5
```

When you have a lot of `days` columns that you'd want to take the `mean` of and multiply with the `sum` of `amount1` and `amount2`, then I'd do it in this manner, without using `myfunc`. But it should be straightforward to implement one if you REALLY need a function.

```
# dummy example
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 200, replace=T), ncol=10))
names(df) <- c(paste0("amount", 1:2), paste0("day", 1:8))
df$idx <- 1:nrow(df) # idx column for uniqueness

# create a data.table
require(data.table)
calc_res <- function(df) {
    dt <- data.table(df)
    # first get the mean
    id1 <- setdiff(names(dt), grep("day", names(dt), value=TRUE))
    dt[, res := rowMeans(.SD), by=id1]
    # now product of sum(amounts) and current res
    id2 <- setdiff(names(dt), names(dt)[1:2])
    dt[, res := sum(.SD) * res, by=id2]
}
dt.fin <- calc_res(df)
```

Comment: I did not mean for you to remove your comment. It was indeed important to note that your solution assumes that the ids are unique; if they are not, it will not give the expected result. I was only asking if you could think of a general answer that uses data.table.

Comment: Awesome! Is there also a way to scale this up to _n_ amounts and days?

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example.  Perhaps the same technique can be used for the real problem:

```
> apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) myfunc(x[1:2], x[3:4]))
## [1]  714.0 2499.0 6382.5
```

As flodel indicates, it is best to use the names for one of the subsetting operations, to ensure that only these columns are used for apply.  A subset is necessary to prevent the vector passed by `apply` from being converted to character, and specifying the columns explicitly means that additional columns in the data frame will not cause this problem.

```
apply(df[c("amount1", "amount2", "day1", "day2")], 1, 
      function(x) myfunc(x[1:2], x[3:4])
     )
```

In practice, I would be more likely to code something like this:

```
amount <- c("amount1", "amount2")
day    <- c("day1", "day2")

df$res <- apply(df[c(amount, day)], 1, function(x) myfunc(x[amount], x[day]))
```

Comment: Instead of `df[-1]`, prefer `df[c("amount1", "amount2", "day1", "day2")]`.

Comment: why Passing the names is better? not easy to maintain solution...Here it easier to remove one column..

Comment: @agstudy: try running all the provided solutions on 1) `df`, 2) `cbind(inserted = "hi", df)`, and 3) `cbind(df, appended = "ho")`. Good code should be robust to any such changes to the input. It requires using column names instead of column indices. And on the contrary it is easier to maintain this way: no need to increment/decrement indices if columns are inserted or removed.

Comment: @flodel I get your point but your solution it is hard to maintain if we change the column names...maybe it is better to use `subset(df,select=-c(id))`. but personally I prefer Arun solution with data.table.

Comment: @agstudy Actually, I almost always use names in my real code (but they're specified as parameters in a list or vector).

Comment: @agstudy: no, the user wants to compute something using "amount1", "amount2", "day1" and "day2". It is only natural that these column names be used. If someone had renamed the columns in the data, then the code should die! So someone can come, notice that the columns have been renamed and modify the code accordingly. If you used column indices, you'd still get a result (no warning or error) and god knows what the result could mean...

Comment: @flodel +1 ok ok :) ! only God know what it means..!